# Creating a counterfactual group for missing values NAs

Tags: r, matching, na

I have a data frame with 17497 observations of 1681 variables that I am working with using R. Some variables are nominal, some are ordinal, some numeric, etc.

I am concentrating on the one that stands for net recalled salary from the previous month (dataframe$q31, where q31 simply denotes question 31 from a questionnaire). The variable is numeric.
It happens so that there are many missing values denoted as NAs. People with managerial and professional positions tend to be more likely not to reveal their income. At the same time there are more likely to earn more. Hence, my further analysis might be distorted.

I would like to create another column with the net recalled salary where the NAs are substituted not with an average, but with the number a given person would be most likely to give taken into consideration preferably all other characteristics from the dataframe.
If not possible, at least its:

- profession (q22isc27, ordinal)
- years of experience (q24c, numeric)
- age (q9age, numeric)
- sex (q8, 1- men, 2 - women)
- year when surveyed (pgssyear, numeric)
- years of education (problematic: for all years q131ed variable available that was filled in by a surveyor itself and is highly approximate, additionally it needs to be recoded into numeric, as somehow it gets displayed as nominal in R; since 1999 q131edr is available that was filled in by surveyed themselves and is ordinal (in spss gets displayed as "scale")
- marital status (q21, ordinal)
- ownership status of the company where employed (q46e, ordinal)
- hours worked per week (q21, numeric)
- weight variable (weight, numeric: it depicts "representativeness" of a person in respect to the whole population) (!)

if possible also region where the respondent lives, but till 1999 there were 49 districts in Poland and afterwards 16, hence there are two variables: voiev49 and voiev16 that are coded as NAs for the invalid years.

I think it might be related to propensity score matching or to these packages that I found online: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/optmatch/optmatch.pdf

Is there any magical way to do it in R?

Comment: The technique you are looking for is called multiple imputation. It has a long history, and there are books written on this subject alone. (Propensity score matching is *not* what you want). I suggest you read about this, and if you have further statistical questions, ask them on Cross Validated, instead of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I will be able to handle it using Amelia package: 
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Amelia/vignettes/amelia.pdf#subsection.4.4
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Amelia/Amelia.pdf

and true, there is lots of materials on it on Cross Validated, e.g.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95832/missing-values-nas-in-the-test-data-when-using-predict-lm-in-r

@nograpes, thank you for all the hints!